# Why isn't my MySQL database being updated on my local server after executing PHP script through iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

This is my signup.php script

[image: This is my signup.php script]

This is what happens when the user enters several text fields in my app and clicks on the sign up button

[image: This is what happens when the user enters several text fields in my app and clicks on the sign up button]

I don't understand why my database won't update. When I click on the "sign up" button , it prints "Success!", but then, when I go to check if the database updated, it didn't. I tried several variations of this code. I just want to make a HTTP POST Request with Swift, I don't even want to read the response I just want to update values in a MySQL database for now.

Yes, the file is in the correct location.
Yes, the names of the columns are written correctly in the PHP file

Comment: Post your code here, not as an image, on a separate site. You are open to SQL injections your code also doesn't have `Success` in it so not sure where that comes from..

Comment: At this point Im just learning later I will cover against SQL injection and other security risks. I'm saying that when I click on the Sign up button , "Success!" is printed in the console, indicating that the Connection was successful.

Comment: I don't know what image 2 is showing, does that `success` mean the PHP script returned a 200?

Comment: Please paste your code into the question directly.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

to your info.plist when doing http request